# Type '...' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' even after type guard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In React I have an object and I'm trying to set a value to a dynamic key property.

Here is my object :

```
interface ITypeOfDev {
   id?: number;
   type: string;
   technologies: ITechUsed[];
   otherTools: string[];
   softSkills: string[];
}

 const typeOfDev: ITypeOfDev = {
   type: 'frontend',
   technologies: [],
   otherTools: [],
   softSkills: [],
}
```

Im my reducer I receive the variable "name" and "value" from the payload, the "name" corresponds to one of my object's key. What I'm trying to do is to check if the value of my received key is an array or not, to set properly the value.

My issue is that even after type checking typescript is complaining saying **Type '...' must have a 'Symbol.iterator'**.

Here is the part of my code that check if it is an array:

```
 let { value } = action.payload;
 const key = action.payload.key as keyof ITypeOfDev;

 if (Array.isArray(state.typeOfDev[key])) value =
 [...state.typeOfDev[key], value];
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         the error
```

I don't know how I can be more precise than that regarding typescript...

Comment: If you aren't comparing arrays across iframes or windows does typescript do what you expect when you swap: `Array.isArray(state.typeOfDev[key])` to `state.typeOfDev[key] instanceof Array` ?

Comment: @JacobSmit unfortunately no, it stays the same...

Comment: I'd suggest assigning `state.typeOfDev[key]` to a `const` and using that instead, you can then easily follow through what ever type typescript has currently inferred at each step of your code. When testing it the playground it seems as if it doesn't trust that `key` hasn't swapped between the condition and where you use it directly after (assigning it to a `const` before hand fixes typescripts trust issues).

Comment: [Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUCeAHCB5GAEQgDdkBvAWAChk7gATAfgC5kQBXAWwCNoBuGnWRgcENgGcwUUAHNBtOpAQALEAHsANutnAIEtnBCYA2gF0Fw9WBXR06rQeRSZIWect0J6mGADKANbAmppOLnIeNAC+NEII6iBSImIExCRsGClEpMgAvBRCSmJsAOQwUAmQIAwlADSFIhCqGtq6+mzm9YrI1rZQ9o4dZl3C3r6BwaFDXTHUNPGJYMgBEJh5yCWiuCXIcBLLqz5oWLippAqx1AtJJHCaHCj5W-jZJCYrmBaXwDDIABQAQSgUDgmAAdMAJECQZg-rd7hAAJSIgrdZDXJZwYGg9YmMH4+EPMzRGhAA)

Comment: Thank you it works, but it's a weird behavior from TypeScript, it will stay a mistery...